# Word for slowly blowing air through an open mouth

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for slowly exhaling through an open mouth like when it's cold and you're trying to warm up your hands?

As in;

He [word] into his hands but failed to warm them up.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a word that means that specifically. _He breathed into his hands but failed to warm them up_ is fine.

Answer (score 2):

to **huff**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/huffing)

huffing

> an act of forcible exhalation

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the tone you're hoping for in your writing, you can use a softer verb or a stronger verb. For example,

Softer verbs:

> He **breathed** into his hands but failed to warm them up.
>
> He **exhaled** into his hands…
>
> He **sighed** into his hands…

Stronger verbs:

> He **blew** into this hands…
>
> He **coughed** into his hands…
>
> He **whispered** into his hands…

Comment: not sure about *sighed* and *whispered*.  They connote something entirely different.

Comment: *Blew* is the word most commonly used in this sentence.